# Java Regexp allow only letters, no leading whitespace, and cannot be empty

Tags: java, android, regex, android-edittext

I'm trying to write a regular expression for an Android project. The widget this is concerning is the MaterialEditText found here https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

This edit text has a method to chain together RegExp validators to it. So far I managed to come up with this.

```
"^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$"
```

When it doesn't match this pattern it shows an error. I need to chain another addValidator to it to check if the edit text is blank, how do i do that?

#### Update

I tried this code

```
editText.addValidator(
            new RegexpValidator("Must contain letters only", "^[A-z][\\sA-z]*$")).addValidator(new RegexpValidator("Cannot be blank","^$"));
```

When its blank, im getting the "Must contain letters only error", and when i type any data i get the "Cannot be blank"

Comment: you mean this `"^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$"` ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I actually had that in my code. I'm not sure why it didn't paste correctly.

Comment: did you want to allow a blank field?

Comment: Your regex has a `*` and can be totally empty. If you want at least one character, use `+`.

Comment: @Avinash Raj, No i do not want to allow blank fields, I would like to add a validator to check for a blank field and show an error.

Comment: @hitch.united did you want to allow spaces at the last?

Comment: No, no leading or trailing white space would be great. It's going to be unnecessary though, I realized I can just trim leading and trailing spaces after it validates.

Comment: In your update, you're requiring that the string contains at least one character, and then requiring that it's blank (since blank is the only thing that matches `^$`).  This seems self-contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your regex does allow the leading whitespace, which your question sounds like it should not.
2. To disallow blank input you could just use `+` instead of `*`, but combined with the fix for #1 this won't be necessary.

Something like this should work: `^[A-z][\sA-z]*$`

Comment: This appears to be working perfectly, would it be possible to split this expression into two separate expressions? For instance, one expression to throw an error if the edit text is blank, and the "^[A-z][\sA-z]*$"?

Comment: `^$` would match an empty string. `^\s*$` would match a string containing nothing, except, maybe whitespace. `\S` would match any string, that contains at least one non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\\s[a-zA-Z]+)*$"
```

This regex won't allow spaces at the beginning or at the end. `+` repeats the previous token one or more times where `*` would repeat the previous token zero or more times.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ9fB2/2